# ColladaLoader TypeError: THREE.LoaderUtils is undefined

Tags: three.js, collada

I'm using three.js and loading a collada file.  It had been working but then all of a sudden stopped and started giving the error:

TypeError: THREE.LoaderUtils is undefined

I'm getting the loader from here:
https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js

and three.js from:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/84/three.min.js

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: have you upgraded the three.js version recently?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same error, try the newer release (it fixed it for me):

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.min.js

Comment: Thanks.  I had reverted to an older version to fix the issue but I'll try updating.